# Nearest station not showing when i switch on back my location

Tags: android, google-maps

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

// data
private final List<StationModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
private final StationAdapter adapter = new StationAdapter(this, list);

// component
private FusedLocationProviderClient mc_fused;
private BottomSheetBehavior mc_behaviour;

// view
private Button mv_show;
private LinearLayout mv_sheet;
private RecyclerView mv_recyler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mc_fused = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mv_show = findViewById(R.id.button_bottom_map_show);
    mv_sheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_container);
    mv_recyler = findViewById(R.id.recycler_bottom_map_station);


    setupBottomSheet();
    setupRecycler();

    if (mapFragment != null)
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    getLocation(map);
}

private void setupBottomSheet() {
    mc_behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mv_sheet);
    mv_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickResult());
}

private void setupRecycler() {
    mv_recyler.setAdapter(adapter);
    mv_recyler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

private void getLocation(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Dexter
            .withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(new CurrentLocationListener(googleMap))
            .check();
}

class CurrentLocationListener implements MultiplePermissionsListener {

    private final GoogleMap map;

    private CurrentLocationListener(GoogleMap map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {

        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {

            mc_fused
                    .getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new LocationListener());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {

    }

    class LocationListener implements OnSuccessListener<Location> {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("You")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_android_deep_orange_500_24dp))
                    .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

            map.addMarker(marker);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 12));

            new StationFinder(map, new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}

class OnClickResult implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mc_behaviour.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            mc_behaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            mv_show.setText(R.string.text_hide);
        } else {
            mc_behaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            mv_show.setText(R.string.text_show);
        }
    }
}

class StationFinder implements GeoQueryEventListener {

    private final GoogleMap map;

    private StationFinder(GoogleMap map, GeoPoint point) {
        this.map = map;

        CollectionReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("stations_index");
        GeoFirestore geo = new GeoFirestore(reference);

        GeoQuery query = geo.queryAtLocation(point, 7);
        query.addGeoQueryEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryError(Exception e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryReady() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String s, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        if (s != null && geoPoint != null) {

            FirebaseFirestore
                    .getInstance()
                    .document("stations/" + s)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            StationModel model = documentSnapshot.toObject(StationModel.class);

                            if (model != null) {
                                list.add(model);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                GeoPoint point = model.getPoint();

                                // mark model station on the map
                                LatLng station = new LatLng(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude());
                                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                                        .title(model.getName())
                                        .position(station);


                                map.addMarker(marker);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyExited(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyMoved(String s, GeoPoint geoPoint) {

    }
}
}
```

---

**Model**

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;

public class StationModel {

private String name;
private String address;
private String country;
private String contact;

private GeoPoint point;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public GeoPoint getPoint() {
    return point;
}

public void setPoint(GeoPoint point) {
    this.point = point;
}
}
```

**Logcat:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
>   com.exzray.womensafetyapp.MapsActivity$CurrentLocationListener$LocationListener.onSuccess(MapsActivity.java:141)  at com.exzray.womensafetyapp.MapsActivity$CurrentLocation

When I open location, it showing the nearest station, but when I turn off the location and reopen back it's showing this error. I need to clear the cache in order to get the nearest police station again. Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `location != null` in `public void onSuccess(Location location) {...}` of `LocationListener` class because `location` can be `null`. Something like that:

```
...
class LocationListener implements OnSuccessListener<Location> {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                   .title("You")
                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_android_deep_orange_500_24dp))
                   .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

            map.addMarker(marker);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 12));

            new StationFinder(map, new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: @brazilwin So, you can accept (check it) the answer ;)